# Galaxy NGS not displaying installed tools

Tags: bioinformatics, galaxy

I'm running an instance of Galaxy NGS in an Ubuntu server, with a basic configuration, postgresql database, and apache.

When I log in as Admin in the Galaxy interface, and try to add a new tool through the tool shed, the tool is installed and I can use it without problems

However, if Galaxy needs to be restarted, the tool does not appear anymore

I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.galaxyproject.org/Admin/Tools/AddToolFromToolShedTutorial) to configure a folder to keep the installed tools, like it explains there, adding a line in config.ini with the desired folder

```
tool_dependency_dir = dependency_dir
```

But that doesn't do the trick and the tools are not stored in the folder anyway

Does somebody have a clue on what could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved after switching from apache to nginx, and changing the line I posted to

```
tool_dependency_dir = /home/galaxy/tool_deps
```

I found a nice resource that helped me with the configuration in case somebody faces the same issue.

https://wiki.galaxyproject.org/Events/BioITWorld2014/W14#Setting_up_a_Local_Galaxy_Tutorial_.28Part_I.29